# PHP get array value and save it to be displayed in another page

Tags: php, onclick, getvalue

I have a page displaying data from an array. When the user click on one of the picture displayed, I would need to save the value $row["Rif"] as I'd need to display the item details in another page.

I was looking around but it seems that Jquery, Ajax are the only available solutions but I don't know these.

Is there any way to implement it using just PHP?

Thank you!

```
 <?php
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                            <div class='property-container'>
                              <div class='property-image'>
                                <img src='img/img02.jpg' alt='test theme'>
                                <div class='property-price'>
                                  " . $row["DescCom"] . "<br>
                                  <span>" . "€ ". $row["Pre"] . " </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class='property-status'>
                                  <span>" . $row["Rif"] . "</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class='property-features'>
                                <span><i class='fa fa-home'></i> " . $row["Mq"] . " m<sup>2</sup></span>
                                <span><i class='fa fa-hdd-o'></i> " . $row["Cam"] . " Cam</span>
                                <span><i class='fa fa-male'></i> Piano " . $row["Pia"] . " </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class='property-content'>
                                <h3>" . $row["TIP"] . "<small>" . $row["Fra"] . "</small></h3>
                                <button type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-warning btn-xs pull-right btn-dettagli'>Details</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>";
                }
            } else {
                echo '0 results';
            }
            $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Comment: why dont you carry the `id` of the product to next page and fetch the entire details there again?

Comment: Hi Fakhruddin,
the while loop is displaying many results how do I know which ID to carry ?
I should carry just the one clicked actually
Thanks

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is stored in `$row["Rif"]`

```
<?php
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                            <div class='property-container'>
                              <div class='property-image'>

 // if this is the image you can hyper-link it to next page that will carry the id as well.

                              <a href='next_page.php?id=". $row['Rif']."><img src='img/img02.jpg' alt='test theme'></a>
                                <div class='property-price'>
                                  " . $row["DescCom"] . "<br>
                                  <span>" . "€ ". $row["Pre"] . " </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class='property-status'>
                                  <span>" . $row["Rif"] . "</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class='property-features'>
                                <span><i class='fa fa-home'></i> " . $row["Mq"] . " m<sup>2</sup></span>
                                <span><i class='fa fa-hdd-o'></i> " . $row["Cam"] . " Cam</span>
                                <span><i class='fa fa-male'></i> Piano " . $row["Pia"] . " </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class='property-content'>
                                <h3>" . $row["TIP"] . "<small>" . $row["Fra"] . "</small></h3>
                                <button type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-warning btn-xs pull-right btn-dettagli'>Details</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>";
                }
            } else {
                echo '0 results';
            }
            $conn->close();
        ?>
```

if this is the image you can hyper-link it to next page that will carry the id as well.

```
<a href='next_page.php?id=". $row['Rif']."><img src='img/img02.jpg' alt='test theme'></a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that 
I think there is a problem with the quotes,if I leave it like that it doesn't work but even if I change to single quotes it doesn't, not sure how to embed your change in it
Thanks

Comment: @ChrisA updated my answer. I had missed out `echo`. Let me know if it works out.

Comment: Hi,
just tried but it's not working, the problem is that it doesn't accept the double quotes we are using in the <a> tag as it's inside an echo. If I change with single quotes it gives me quotes error again on the same line
Thank you

Comment: @ChrisA sorry I missed out that you were implementing it in PHP. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Hi works!! Sorry to bother, last question, where is this value stored? I tried to echo $_GET['Rif'] in "next_page.php" but it's not set
Thanks a lot

Comment: @ChrisA when you mouse over the link can you see the value on the bottom left corner of browser? Also what is the link you get on the new page. Please give me that.

Comment: Hey, got it working just now, I was echoing the wrong variable name
 echo $_GET['Rif'] whereas you called it "id ". So in the end doing :
echo $_GET['id'] works fine 
Thanks a lot, you have been super helpful !